# How do I remove dns nameserver 169.252.169.254 on GCP instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, nameservers

On GCP, after I delpoyed an ubuntu 16.04 instance, it has a default nameserver 169.254.169.254 in its /etc/resolv.conf

I don't want to use it, so I went to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base (Which was blank when I first open) and added my own nameserver

After running sudo resolvconf -u, my own nameserver showed in /etc/resolv.conf but it is under that 169.254.169.254

As long as 169.254.169.254 is responsible, my own nameserver won't be used....

I'm just wondering how to remove that 169.254.169.254.....

Comment: What John Hanley said. Don't mess with resolve.conf manually. That's a great way to render your machine inaccessible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not modify /etc/resolve.conf. This is managed by Google Cloud DHCP and is overwritten every 60 minutes and at DHCP refresh. Unless you have a good reason, do not disable/remove Google nameservers.

Instead, prepend your name servers to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

```
prepend domain-name-servers 172.16.1.1;
```

Answer (score 3):

From Google Cloud's [VPC Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#alwaysallowed):

> Google runs a local metadata server alongside each instance at 169.254.169.254. This server is essential to the operation of the instance, so the instance can access it regardless of any firewall rules you configure.

So, leave it there.